# Ошибка при закрытии Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, обновление

При закрытии Visual studio code вылетает слудующая ошибка, сообщающая о том что не удалось установить обновление кода Visual studio code, какое обновление? Не знаю, в принципе так же как и решить данную проблему. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файл лога добавьте, текстом. Так же написано, попробуйте перезагрузить машину перед установкой обновления

Comment: В том то и дело, я скачал и поставил новую версию и ничего не обновлял, а после перезагрузок ничего не менялось

Comment: Логи добавьте сюда в вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался, быстрая перестановка Visual studio решила проблему